# Not able to implement Google tag manager in Gmail Addon or Google workspace addon

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-workspace-add-ons

I went through the documentation provided [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/tag-manager) but couldn't find any code to implement google tag manager in gmail addon and to push data to GTM event. I also tried finding a way to implement google tag manager script provided at [Quick Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) but nowhere found a way to implement the same in gmail addon (apps script).

Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Workspace Addons do not expose the browser DOM so there is no standard way for you to load/embed a GTM container snippet using the typical methods.

When you embed a GTM container snippet in a webpage it loads a series of tag scripts, so you'd need to find some way to emulate that from server-side GAS.

As a starting point, you can fetch the gtm.js script for your container by going to:

`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-xxxxx`

You could then try embedding that script in your GAS project but then you'd have to refactor that code to work from server-side GAS, which does not natively support the DOM methods common to client-side JavaScript that runs inside a browser.

You might be able to create your own polyfills (or leverage existing libraries from a resource like NPM), but you'd have to do a lot of work mapping DOM code to their Apps Script equivalents where possible.